# Transit visa or general visa

Tags: visas, uk, transit, indian-citizens, paperwork

Indian green card holder traveling from NY to India with a layover of 11 hours in London. Do I need a transit visa to go and sightsee London?

Comment: Why so many down votes?  It is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need any visa. Just present your passport, filled-out landing card, green card and boarding passes.

You can then stay until 23:59 the next day.